# Is there a way to easily see currently defined faces?

Tags: faces, themes

I often find that I need to define faces for custom commands. I prefer to inherit from faces defined by the current theme, to keep things visually consistent.

`M-x list-faces-display` lists the faces, but it doesn't display a preview. It's just a list of face names and then the alphabet, formatted with the default "link" face.

Is there a way for me to easily visualise what faces are defined by the current theme? Is there a way for me to easily visualise all currently defined faces across the board?

---

**Edit:** `M-x list-faces-display` is not giving me a preview. Here is what it looks like with the `leuven` theme:

[image: <code>list-faces-display</code> under the Leuven theme]

And here is what it looks like with `zenburn`:

[image: <code>list-faces-display</code> under the Zenburn theme]

If I disable my init file, I can get previews working again. The previews do actually appear to be in the correct face, but they are displaying as buttons. Is there any reason having the `button` property set to `t` or being in the `help-face-button` category would override the underlying face?

Comment: It may behoove you to recursively bisect your user-configuration (by commenting stuff out and restarting Emacs) to find out why `list-faces-display` works correctly with `emacs -q`, but not when loading your user-configuration.  The right column should be a rainbow of colors, with a variety of fonts.

Comment: I haven't messed about with text properties myself but if all else fails I will. Each of the text previews is in the relevant font when I inspect the text. However, they are displaying as `button`. Is there any reason having the `button` property set to `t` would override the default face? Is there a way to manually override that? I'd rather apply a patch to whatever changed that than disable packages outright.

Comment: In my emacs, the `button` property is indeed set on the sample texts, because they are indeed buttons. But also, the `face` property is set to the face being displayed, and that determines the look of the text. Before bisecting, try to run emacs with the `-Q` argument. If the problem still occurs, your emacs installation appears to be broken somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see all faces currently defined: **`M-x list-faces-display`**.  It **does** show a preview. It does **not** show the samples using the "*default 'link' face*".

The Emacs manual, as usual, is your friend. `C-h r i face TAB`, choose `faces`.

That takes you to node [Faces](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Faces.html).

---

If you use library [Facemenu+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FaceMenuPlus) then `list-faces-display` is enhanced a bit.

Comment: `M-x list-faces-display` is not showing a preview on my box. It works if I disable my init file, otherwise it displays with face `button`. I've added some screenshots. There are no hooks or anything that modify how faces are displayed, and previews work in the customize menu and individual face help menus.

Comment: Clearly, something in your init file is causing you the grief. As usual, recursively bisect it until you find the culprit. You can use `M-x comment-region` to comment-out the region. And with plain `C-u` the command UNcomments the region. This is a binary search, so it is very quick to do (even if it doesn't seem like it at first).